# simplest way to enable user (non-root) to suspend laptop

Tags: power-management, suspend, d-bus, pm-utils

My laptop has `suspend` capability:

```
# cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem
```

and indeed I can suspend as root:

```
echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
```

This works fine. But what would be a minimalist way to enable user (non-root) to suspend ?

I am using Debian Buster, but I don't have `systemd` installed (I am using old style sysvinit). And I don't have udev daemon running either (I am using the "kernel space" udev).

**I would like to achieve user suspend capability with minimal additional packages required.**

On earlier Debian version (Wheezy), I could install:

- pm-utils
- upower

and then issue a command via dbus. I think it was something like this:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

this no longer works. Now I have read that `upower` has changed and the curent verison in Debian `0.99.10` is not supposed to work. but I installed `upower` from wheezy (`0.9.17`), just to test it, but that does not work either. The `dbus-send` command gives me this error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 127
```

But using `pm-utils`, `upower` and `dbus` might not be the simplest setup anyway. What is actually the purpose of `pm-utils` of `upower`? Those utilities only work for root. But as root, I already can suspend with `echo -n mem > /sys/power/state`. What do those utilities bring extra?

I see pm-utils installs lots of various scripts. What else do I need to handle besides issuing `echo -n mem > /sys/power/state` ?

And how could I achieve all that as user ?

Perhaps writing a simple `C` program that writes `mem` to `/sys/power/state`, and set the `s` bit same as for instance `/usr/bin/passwd` has.

Would this be a workable and clean solution? Or would this be considered a "dirty" solution? Are there better solutions?

What else do I need to handle, besides writing `mem` to `/sys/power/state`?

Do I need to `ifdown` and `ifup` the network ?

Comment: There are many questions there, I believe it needs to be more focused. I would go for the C program with the `s` bit, looks totally clean and simple.

Comment: Do `sync` (Read `man sync`).

Comment: `ifdown` and ` ifup` are good things. Post-suspend `ifup` will reinvigorate your network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple program in `c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f;

        f = fopen("/sys/power/state", "w");

    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file: /sys/power/state\n");   
        exit(1);             
    }

    fprintf(f,"%s","mem");

    fclose(f);

}
```

Compile it, and copy the binary to `/usr/local/bin/pm-suspend`.
Set the setuid bit:

```
chmod u+s pm-suspend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow specific set of suspend commands to be used without a password using sudo:

Create an `/etc/sudoers.d/suspend` file containing:

```
Cmnd_Alias     SUSPEND = /usr/bin/systemctl suspend, /usr/sbin/rtcwake ^-m mem --date [0-9+][^ ]{0,30}$, /usr/sbin/rtcwake ^-m mem -[st] [0-9]{1,11}$
yourusername   ALL=NOPASSWD: SUSPEND
```